# How can I convert data held as 01010 bits into fields in a class object?

Tags: c#

I have two variables that contain true/false data. THe first variable can be null but the second variable is always non null. Both variables will always be the same length.

```
var AnswerGridCorrect = "000111"; // or null
var AnswerGridResponses = "000011";
```

How could I change this data into an object oriented form. I already created classes and these are below. Here's is what I need the output to look like when converted to JSON:

```
"answers":[        // Json conversion made Answers into answers
   {"correct":null,"response":true},
   {"correct":null,"response":true},
   {"correct":null,"response":true},
   {"correct":null,"response":false}
 }
```

Note that I am using LINQ to output the data so I think what I need is a function with parameters something like this:

```
 .Select((t, index) => new  {
                Answer = t.Answer,
                Answers = makeAnswer(t.AnswerGridCorrect,
                                     t.AnswerGridResponses)
                });
```

I am not sure if this helps but here were the classes I was using when I did this from JSON:

```
public class AnswerRow
{
    public bool? Correct { get; set; }
    public bool Response { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerRowList
{
    public IList<AnswerRow> AnswerRows { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why is correct null and not true/false?

Comment: Assuming `correct="011"` and `responses="001"` are input is this desired output: `{{false, false}, {false, true}, {true, true}} as IEnumerable<class {bool correct; bool response;}>`?

Comment: @rene - Thanks for your helpful comment. I should have pointed out that if the questions are not yet marked then the answerGridCorrect will be null. However the answerGridResponses will always have a value as the responses are assumed all false if not yet answered.

Comment: @Dialecticus - I have the classes AnswerRow and AnswerRowList that I created. I would like to have the output as an instance of AnswerRowList. I think this might make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation for your makeAnswers method:

```
public List<AnswerRow> makeAnswers(string c, string r)
{
   var result = new List<AnswerRow>();
   for(var i=0; i<r.Length; i++)
   {
       result.Add(
        new AnswerRow { 
                 Correct = c!=null?new Nullable<bool>(c[i]=='1'):null,
                 Response = r[i]=='1'
        });
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: I am checking this out now. thanks. I will update this post when I'm sure everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Rene's answer is probably correct, but here's the (unnecessarily complex) Linq way:

```
AnswerRowList MakeAnswer(string answerGridCorrect, string answerGridResponses)
{
    return new AnswerRowList()
    {
        AnswerRows = answerGridResponses.Zip(
            answerGridCorrect == null ?
                Enumerable.Repeat<bool?>(null, answerGridResponses.Length) :
                answerGridCorrect.Select(x => new Nullable<bool>(x == '1')),
            (r, c) => new AnswerRow()
            {
                Correct = c,
                Response = r == '1'
            }).ToList()
    };
}
```